# Minecraft modding Java exception in mod item class

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

This is my code, I have errors on line 16 and 17, i don't know where im going wrong, this is in the main ModItems class and i have been using this video as a [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjyTE_gNID8&list=PLpKu3PfwdqHRA8aoa4RAzO9camNR9Tm45&index=4) If you need the rest of my class files i have uploaded the current copy of my classes [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5_jhxIMIihldkFZVFBXU2c0bUk)

The error on both lines is ***The constructor Item(Item, Item) is undefined***

```
 package TheStraying11.QuarkyPower.init;

import TheStraying11.QuarkyPower.Reference;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemSoup;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import TheStraying11.QuarkyPower.items.QuarkUp;
import TheStraying11.QuarkyPower.items.QuarkDown;

public class ModItems {

    public static Item QuarkUp;
    public static Item QuarkDown;

    public static void init() {
        QuarkUp = new Item(QuarkUp, QuarkUp);
        QuarkDown = new Item(QuarkDown, QuarkDown);
    }
    public static void register() {
        registerItem(QuarkUp);
        registerItem(QuarkDown);
    }
    public static void registerRenders() {

    }
    public static void registerItem(Item item) {
        GameRegistry.register(item);
    }

    public static void registerRender(Item item) {
        ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(item, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(new ResourceLocation(Reference.MODID, item.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5)), "inventory"));

    }
}
```

Comment: https://takahikokawasaki.github.io/minecraft-resources/javadoc/forge/1.8-11.14.1.1320/net/minecraft/item/Item.html#Item()

Comment: The error states pretty exactly what the issue is. The object 'Item' does not own a constructor that takes two 'Item' objects as parameter. 'Item' has only one constructor, which takes no arguments.

Comment: @AndrewLi Im confused on what to use instead? im just trying to create the item, everything else is already set up

Comment: @Korashen Yeah, i know but i dont know why because the guide i was following had ItemTinIngot (the name of the item he was creating) so i tried ItemQuarkUp and it didn't work, eclipse suggested to use just Item but like his code worked, so i dont understand really because all i did was change item and variable names

Comment: @JackRycroft I did not watch the whole video, it's too long for now. But I scrubbed through it and he defined a class ItemTinIngot and he also defined a constructor within it, that takes two parameters. At 1:37 in the video. And when he is creating an instance at 6:17, he is ustin that constructor, that he made by himself, not the one from net.minecraft.item.Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

friend helped, changed

```
QuarkUp = new Item(QuarkUp, QuarkUp);
QuarkDown = new Item(QuarkDown, QuarkDown);
```

to

```
quark_Up = new itemQuarkUp();
quark_Down = new itemQuarkDown();
```

EDIT:

Completely started again as that video just made a mess imo, that i didn't understand, I guess ill get better soon haha, i just wish i could use Python instead

Comment: Considering that your original code tries to pass the constructed item to its own constructor, you end up passing null. So that would never work (and why would you need to pass an item instance to its *own* constructor anyway? what could that possibly accomplish that `this.` couldn't?)

Comment: @Draco18s Like i said in my edit just now,  i was using a video, that was a complete mess. It made no sense to me, but i found a new video that is better, its my first mod so im going to have trouble getting through the first time, but i'll learn and get better soon enough. I haven't used much Java before this, i spent like 1hr on codecademy learning it instead of doing my computer science work in the lesson haha.

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, I highly recommend [Shadowfacts](https://shadowfacts.net/tutorials/)

Comment: @Draco18s okay, thanks i'll check that out. Closing the thread now aswell